# AWS S3 has no construct signatures

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am facing an issue while trying to use a constructor signature for my aws s3 bucket.

I have the below import:

```
import * as S3 from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
```

With the below s3 signature:

```
private static getS3Bucket(): any {
    return new S3(
        {
            accessKeyId: 'myAccessId',
            secretAccessKey: 'mySecretKey',
            region: 'us-west-2'
        }
    );
}
```

But I am receiving the below compiler error in my S3 return object:

> This expression is not constructable.   Type 'typeof
> import("D:/myWorkspace/Typescript/myProject/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-types/index")'
> has no construct signatures.ts(2351)

Went through a couple of GIT issues and updated my:

```
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.55.0",
```

and

```
"@aws-sdk/types": "^3.1.0",
```

But no luck. Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: `import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";` and use `new S3Client({ ... })`. By the way, either your function is mis-named or the code it's trying to execute is incorrect. It's named `getS3Bucket()` but is returning an S3 client, not a bucket.

Comment: Oh. I was earlier using `import * as S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';` and it was working perfectly fine. Now looks like the module name is changed and some of my code got messed up.